# Is CSLA.NET a right solution for multiple databases?

Tags: c#, .net, csla

I have an application the currently connect to a database. But I have a plan to slice the data in this database to multiple databases.

For example, I have 10,000 records in table Test_Table_1 and right now it is located in the only one database. Now, I want to move 5,000 records from this database to a new database, with the same table name. So, I would have 2 databases, the original one would contain the first 5,000 records and the new data-center would contain the rest (5,000 records.)

The challenge is on the application. I need to update it by reading a configuration value from a configuration file to check which data center it would connect to.

Here are my questions:

1. Is CSLA.NET a right solution for this problem?
2. Is there a feature on CSLA.NET that allow me to switch between data-centers when one of them dead?

Comment: Inigo Montoya: "You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means" - I think you mean Database.  A data center is a gigantic facility with many servers within it.

Comment: @MystereMan I changed the word you suggested in my questions, thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 2):

CSLA is not a data access framework or ORM, it is a business layer framework.

It does abstract the concept of the database, making it possible for your business layer to use data from multiple databases.

Interaction with the database(s) is the responsibility of your data access layer (DAL). CSLA provides some high level functionality so it invokes your DAL in a consistent manner, but it is up to you to implement your DAL.

One important consideration when building business domain objects that include data from multiple databases is that the *key* values from each database table are usually required to do any database updates if the user saves the object's data. As a result you should expect to store those key values in your business object (perhaps as private properties). The same is true for concurrency values such as timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

CSLA is not a data access framework. It provides business objects methods that abstract the data access implementation. But you would still have to implement the data access layer using ADO .NET/some kind of ORM/etc.

I would look into NHibernate and the Shards package.

http://nhforge.org/

http://nuget.org/packages/NHibernate.Shards/

Comment: I would add that nh can complement csla.